# How do I create a UIView with top corners rounded, bottom corners normal, and a border around this whole view?

Tags: swift

[image]

This is what I'm getting with this code

```
private func setupBorders(){
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: mainTableView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    mainTableView.layer.mask = maskLayer
    mainTableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    mainTableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
}
```

MainTableView is a uiview containing the notepad table and the table header.  If I can get it to work for any UIView then it will work for this one.  Much appreciation to anyone who can help!

Edit:  In case its not clear, the problem is the border disappears on the rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

A mask layer is not enough to solve your requirement, because the layer border will not respect to the layer mask. Instead you should create a view for drawing the backgound and the border, and it should clip its contents along the border, too.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard drag a UIView to your ViewController, set constrains as you want, link it to NewView and try this,

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet var NewView :UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let HeightFloat :CGFloat = screenSize.height - 60
        let WidthFloat :CGFloat = screenSize.width - 50

        let NewRect :CGRect = CGRectMake(10, 20, WidthFloat, HeightFloat)

        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: NewRect,
                                    byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight],
                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = maskPath.CGPath
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
        shape.lineWidth = 2
        shape.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound

        NewView.layer.mask = shape


    }

}
```

You will get your output,
[image]